# Repeated article in a sentence

Tags: articles

Which sentence is correct? The book suggests that "C" is the correct answer, but somehow I feel all three sentences are correct too. Any help?

```
a)The firefighters save the people from the fire.
b)The firefighters save people from the fire.
c)The firefighters save people from fire.
```

Comment: There's also just *firefighters save people from fires*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A** would be correct if we're talking about saving specific people from a specific fire accident that took place.
(For example, The fire fighters saved the people from the fire of California last year).

Similarly, **B** would be correct if only the fire accident is specific.

As the sentence is in simple present tense, hence it is a general fact that is being told about firefighters, rather than about a specific event. Hence "**C**" is correct.

Comment: The reason for ruling out A and B is indeed the use of present simple. By using the definite article "the", these answers suggest a specific event, but they should go with present progressive or past simple.